# JRebel not reload changes

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, jrebel

i have a project built with jhipster (spring-boot).
run my project with Run Configuration from Eclipse IDE:

```
clean spring-boot:run -Dmaven.test.skip="true" -Drebel.remoting_plugin="true"
```

every time i save changes, jrebel give me error like the following:

```
[2017-12-03 22:15:55] [Project my-project, server localhost] Connecting to server to sync project
[2017-12-03 22:15:55] Unexpected response from server. Raw Headers: {date=Sun, 03 Dec 2017 15:15:55 GMT, allow=GET, HEAD, expires=0, transfer-encoding=chunked, x-xss-protection=1; mode=block, x-content-type-options=nosniff, connection=keep-alive, content-type=application/json;charset=UTF-8, cache-control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, pragma=no-cache, x-application-context=my-project:swagger,dev:8080}
[2017-12-03 22:15:55] Unexpected response from server. First kilobyte of content:
[2017-12-03 22:15:55] {
  "timestamp" : "2017-12-03T15:15:55.499+0000",
  "status" : 405,
  "error" : "Method Not Allowed",
  "exception" : "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
  "message" : "Request method 'POST' not supported",
  "path" : "/"
}

[2017-12-03 22:15:55] [Project my-project, server localhost] Synchronization failed! JRebel remote server did not respond. The remote server has to be started with the JVM argument: -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true.
[2017-12-03 22:15:55] Synchronization took 42 ms in total.
```

what is actually happen?
how to solve this?

my environment:
- macOS
- jRebel 7.1.3
- spring-boot 1.5.9.RELEASE

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **TL;DR**

Don't use `-Drebel.remoting_plugin=true`.

Instead use *Help > JRebel > Configuration > Startup > Run locally from command line.*

---

### **The long version.**

Based on your description, it sounds like you're running the Spring Boot application on your own machine.

The argument `-Drebel.remoting_plugin=true` should only be used when the actual application is on a **different machine** (or virtual machine) from the IDE (eclipse) you are using.

You also don't need to use the JRebel Eclipse plugin `synchronize` feature. JRebel will itself monitor for changes to class files in the `target/classes` directory. 
When you build your project with either Eclipse or with `mvn compile`, then JRebel will detect the changes and reload the classes.

So remove the remoting argument and instead use the following instructions: In Eclipse, go to *Help > JRebel > Configuration > Startup > Run locally from command line.* Then choose your JVM and Spring Boot.

Find the instructions for the Maven Spring Boot plugin and use them for adding the JRebel agent to your application.

---

Also, you can't just add JVM arguments to `spring-boot:run` by adding them to the end of the command. Instead you should add the arguments to a `MAVEN_OPTS` environmental argument or pass them with `-Drun.jvmArguments="-Dsome.argument"`

Comment: thanks for your explanations.
it runs well on command line as your suggested.